# Why is this reversed StringBuilder not equal to the original String, when it is a palindrome?

Tags: java, equals, stringbuilder

I was trying to check that a String is a palindrome using `StringBuilder` and `reverse()`. For a word with no symmetry like "chan" it correctly returns `false`, but it also returns `false` for genuine palindromes like "madam".

Code:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("madam");
StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder(str);
boolean res = str2.equals(str.reverse().toString().trim());
System.out.println(str + " " + str2);
System.out.println(res);
```

Output:

```
madam madam
false
```

I am running Eclipse Neon with Java 8.

Comment: Use a debugger to find it out.

Comment: You compare a String with a StringBuilder.

Comment: why do you need to trim the result?

Comment: even not working after rermoving trim()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`str.reverse().toString().trim()` is a `String`, so it cannot be equal to a `StringBuilder`.

Try to compare 2 `String`s instead:

```
boolean res=str2.toString().equals(str.reverse().toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare strings, you need to use `str2.toString()`:

```
boolean res=str2.toString().equals(str.reverse().toString().trim());
```

Full solution:

```
StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder("madam");
StringBuilder str2=new StringBuilder(str);
boolean res=str2.toString().equals(str.reverse().toString().trim());
System.out.println(str+" "+str2);
System.out.println(res);
```

Output:

```
 madam madam true
```

The problem is that you are comparing a StringBuilder object `str2` with a String, instead of comparing the two Strings.
Furthermore, `trim()` is not needed as your String contains only letters.

Answer (score 2):

This line is comparing `str2`, an instance of `StringBuilder`, with an instance of `String`:

```
boolean res = str2.equals(str.reverse().toString().trim());
```

It's common for objects of two different classes to always say they are not equal, because they aren't generally programmed to know how to examine the contents of different types of object. (There are some cases where it's specified to work, such as different implementations of `java.util.List`.)

**In this case, it's even worse, because `StringBuilder` does not override the `equals` method *at all*.** If you check [the class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), you'll see `equals` listed as one of the methods inherited from `Object`. So it will return `true` only when passed the same object instance; it *never* compares *content*.

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("abc");
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(sb1);
System.out.println(sb1.equals(sb1)); // true; same object
System.out.println(sb1.equals(sb2)); // false; different objects (same content)
```

So you cannot compare *any* `StringBuilder` instances this way. To do the comparison, convert your reversed result back to a plain `String`:

```
String input = "madam";
input = input.trim();
String reversed = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(input + " " + reversed);
System.out.println(input.equals(reversed));
```

Note: If you want to `trim()` a user input, do it at the earliest moment. If you trim after reversal, you will have to trim both halves of the comparison.